# copying UIScrollView to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I have a camera view which the user can zoom in and out using a scrollview, no problem.

The issue is when i need to apply the same exact zoom and location to another scrollview and everything goes wrong. Not only am i not too sure how to do it exactly, But it presents some odd behavior.

so i have

previewScrollView - the scroll view used in previewing the camera image.

scrollview - the scrollview for the picture taken.

and i have two seperate views one which is the preview camera layer of type UIView before they take the picture

and a UIPictureView for after the picture is taken

so i have something like this.

```
_viewToScroll = photoImage;
[_scrollView setZoomScale:[_previewScrollView zoomScale]];
[_scrollView setContentScaleFactor:[_previewScrollView contentScaleFactor]];
[_scrollView zoomToRect:CGRectMake(-160, -240, 320 / _scrollView.zoomScale, 480 / _scrollView.zoomScale)animated:NO];

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return _viewToScroll;
}
```

And nothing comes of it, just sits there unzoomed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following

```
[_scrollView setZoomScale:[_previewScrollView zoomScale]];
[_scrollView setContentOffset:[_previewScrollView contentOffset]];
```

and in the protocol function

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return scrollView;
}
```